# Java Socket Delay continued

Tags: java, sockets

I am sending ascii over a socket like this:

```
outputStreamWriter(s + (char) 13);
outputStreamWriter.flush();
```

Out in the field, there can be a 10 to 30 second delay between flush() and the data being sent over the network (verified using wireshark).

In order to test the socket connection I use this:

```
public final boolean isConnected() {
  try {
    socket.sendUrgentData(32);
    return true;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    return false;
  }
```

When I get rid of the sendUrgentData and just return true in isConnected(), the delay goes away.

Using the protocol analyser, I've noticed that the large chunks of data I am sending end up getting marked as urgent just like the single byte I am sending to test the socket. Counter intuitively it is the large urgent packets that end up getting delayed.

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 3):

> I am sending ascii over a socket like this:

```
outputStreamWriter(s + (char) 13);
```

No you aren't. That code doesn't even compile.

> In order to test the socket connection I use this

Futile. That doesn't test the socket connection. It just sends some output. It is subject to the same issues as just writing to the output: the socket send buffer, retries, timeouts, the receiver's socket receive buffer, and the receive window. It doesn't tell you whether the connection is still good. Nothing can, apart from just writing to the connection and catching the IOExceptions, which will pretty definitely not happen on the first write after a disconnect.

The other problem with sending a space at arbitrary intervals is that the receiver has to understand and ignore them. Does it?

Comment: +1: AFAIK, the only way sure to know the other end is receiving your data is to have the other end send back data which indicate it has.

Comment: The receiver handles the space well, and my isConnected() function works well too (except for introducing a delay somehow).

Comment: Sorry about the small code fragments, but I am in the classified domain and can only retype unclassified code.

Comment: By sending a byte with sendUrgentData before sending the actual message, I am able to detect the failure of the socket (when IOException thrown), and save my message for the future when the socket is connected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try turning nagle off (Socket.setTcpNoDelay()) however this delay is usually up to 40 to 200 ms depending on the OS. I have never seen something which causes a multi-second delay (except a full GC which doubt is the cause here)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I did setTcpNoDelay(true) and the delay is still there.